# Select2 clear 'x' button to set default value?

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is it possible that pressing "x" button on Select2 dropdown with `allowClear` enabled set default (predefined) value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onchange event. Check if the value is empty and set the value to whatever predefined is.

```
$("select").on("change", function (e) {
   if($(this).val()==""){
      $(this).val("predefined value");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Select2 allows you to associate the placeholder with an id other than a blank string.

```
$("select").select2({
  placeholder: {
    id: "the_predefined_value",
    text: "The placeholder text"
  }
});
```

So when you click on the "x", it will set the value to `the_predefined_value` and display the placeholder text. You are going to need an `<option>` with a `value` of `the_predefined_value` in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The code i have written below will work for you,

```
$(".myselect").select2({
     placeholder: "Select a option",
     allowClear: true,
     width: '100%'
 }).off('select2:clear').on('select2:clear', (e) => {
     $(e.currentTarget).val("predefined value");
 });
```